# Number of paths through a grid

Tags: project-euler

I am attempting to solve Project Euler prob. 204 by hand, and I decided that this method should help a lot.

I have the following grid:

[image]

The numbers indicate the total number of paths from a node at the base to all the nodes on the top. Conditions below apply.

The width and height can go up to infinity. A node can only connect to one that is above its row, and that is either directly above or anywhere to the right of the node (If it was not understood by the first restriction, a node cannot connect to one that is *directly* to the right. Must be 1 above.).

Is there a formula that can show the number of paths through the grid above, with any given width and height? If so, please explain.

Comment: Have you learnt graph theory?

Comment: Sorry, but none at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**.  Suppose you want to get from a starting node to a node at most $n$ steps to the right and $m$ steps above.  You will have to visit exactly one node at each level above the start; say the node visited at level $k$ is $a_k$ steps to the right of the start.  Then we have
$$0\le a_1\le a_2\le\cdots\le a_{m-1}\le a_m\le n\ ,\tag{$*$}$$
and conversely, each $m$-tuple $(a_1,\ldots,a_m)$ will give a possible path.  So, you need to count the number of $m$-tuples satisfying $(*)$.

One way to do this: let $b_k=a_k+k$ for each $k$.  Then we need
$$0<b_1<b_2<\cdots<b_{m-1}<b_m\le n+m\ .$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yup, that's the good place to start ; +1, that was a good hint.

Comment: May by a silly question, but what does the (*) represent? I'm a bit confused on what exactly a (m-1)-tuple should satisfy.

Comment: E.g, if $m=4$, $n=6$, $a_1=3$, $a_2=3$, $a_3=4$ it represents the path $$(0,0)\to(1,3)\to(2,3)\to(3,4)\to(4,6)\ .$$

Comment: It finally got to me that the $(*)$ stands for the condition you listed. Truly, I knew that this condition applied when I was searching for a pattern. Unless I'm missing what I'm looking for, this doesn't seem to answer the question. My question is _how_ to get the number of tuples satisfying the condition.

Comment: @user3373311 : Count! This answer gives you a hint as to *how* to count it. If you want a full answer, then ask for it.

Comment: user3373311, see slight revision and additional hint.  @PatrickDaSilva FYI ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your patience with this question. While I have not used your hint _entirely_ in my solution, your answer has got me to illustrate some further examples, and realize that the number of paths is associated with Pascal's triangle. Once again, thanks for the help. I have marked this as answered.